# How to create an installer for a Java EE Web application in a single installer?

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, web-applications, java

Is there a way to create an installer that contains a whole Java EE Web app, and where the final user only has to execute a single installer without the need to install a whole production environment?

What I'm trying to do is to save them the installation of JDK + Tomcat, if you have a better solution, please provide it.

Comment: Did you mean embedding Tomcat?

Comment: @PaulVargas Tomcat, or any servlet container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more simplest way would be to create a compressed file with all files that you need (Tomcat and JDK). Upon unzipping the file, this could run a command to start Tomcat or what you require. It will be necessary to consider that the **paths** to the Tomcat and to the JDK to be *the same* as in the original environment.

I saw that [Winrar](http://www.rarlab.com/) can generate executable file and cans run a command at the end of extraction. (Have you seen this when you install a new program? First unzipping, then install. ) This at least in Windows. Other libraries or programs might generate something like Winrar.

Answer (score 3):

For Windows environement you can create installer as follows as same you can prepare as by creating shell script for linux environment.

1, Package the binary distributions of the s/w (e.g. postgresql, jetty, jre etc...)

2, put your war file in jetty webapps

3, create data folder inside postgres

4, setting various environment variables and initialization using batch file. In my case I created following "install.bat" file.

```
REM set jdk environment
PATH=%~dp0Java\jre6\bin;%~dp0Java\jre6\lib;%~dp0pgsql\bin;%PATH%
setx PATH "%PATH%"

REM set postgres environment
SETX PGDATA "%~dp0pgsql\data"
SETX PGDATABASE postgres
SETX PGUSER postgres
SETX PGPORT 5432
SETX PGLOCALEDIR "%~dp0pgsql\share\locale"

REM initdb initialize the postgresql initialization properties
"%~dp0pgsql\bin\initdb" -D "%~dp0pgsql\data" -U postgres -A trust

REM put the temp.vbs script into startup
cscript //NoLogo //B "%~dp0start_startup_shortcut.vbs"
cscript //NoLogo //B "%~dp0start_desktop_shortcut.vbs"
cscript //NoLogo //B "%~dp0app_shortcut.vbs"
REM start the database service
"%~dp0pgsql\bin\pg_ctl" -D "%~dp0pgsql\data" start

timeout /T 10

"%~dp0pgsql\bin\createdb.exe" -U postgres dbName
"%~dp0pgsql\bin\psql.exe" -U postgres -d dbName -f "%~dp0backup.sql"

REM java -DSTART="%~dp0jetty8\start.ini" -jar "%~dp0jetty8\start.jar"

REM start the jetty server
java -Djetty.home="%~dp0jetty8" -jar "%~dp0jetty8\start.jar" > pb_log.txt


pause
```

5, create batch file to start services. For example "start.bat"

```
REM start the database service

"%~dp0pgsql\bin\pg_ctl" -D "%~dp0pgsql\data" start

java -Djetty.home="%~dp0jetty8" -jar "%~dp0jetty8\start.jar"
```

6, You can create application shortcuts as follows. For example "app_shortcut.vbs"

```
Dim FileName
FileName = "projectName"

Set wsShell= CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Set wshSysEnv = wsShell.Environment("PROCESS")

sMyHomePath = wshSysEnv("HOMEPATH")

Set shortcut =
wsShell.CreateShortcut(CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop")& + "\" + 
FileName + ".lnk")

shortcut.Description = "Start projectName"

currentDirectory = left(WScript.ScriptFullName,
(Len(WScript.ScriptFullName))-(len(WScript.ScriptName)))

shortcut.TargetPath = currentDirectory + "projectName.bat"

shortcut.Arguments = "/Arguments:Shortcut"

shortcut.Save
```

7, Start service desktop shortcuts as follows:

```
Dim FileName
FileName = "Start projectName Server"

Set wsShell= CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Set wshSysEnv = wsShell.Environment("PROCESS")

sMyHomePath = wshSysEnv("HOMEPATH")

Set shortcut = 
wsShell.CreateShortcut(CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop")& + "\" + 
FileName + ".lnk")

shortcut.Description = "Start projectName"

currentDirectory = left(WScript.ScriptFullName,
(Len(WScript.ScriptFullName))-(len(WScript.ScriptName)))

shortcut.TargetPath = currentDirectory + "start.bat"

shortcut.Arguments = "/Arguments:Shortcut"

shortcut.Save
```

8, Run application batch file

```
@echo off
netstat -o -n -a | findstr 0.0:9095
if %ERRORLEVEL% equ 0 (start http://localhost:9095) ELSE (echo "Please Start the Server"
pause)
```

Answer (score 1):

While a single installer may give the appearance of convenience it can start to be problematic in a number of use cases:

- when Tomcat, the JDK or some other component has to be upgraded to resolve a security issue. It is easier for end users to do this with separate installers and you don't have to create a new installer with the updated bits
- some users may want to run you application on a different app server to the one you bundle
- if every app did this, users would end up with one JDK install + one container install for every app

Since both the JVM install and Tomcat install are trivial, I'd recommend shipping your app with some nice, clear installation instructions rather than as a single package. YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

If your web application is just a single WAR file and you can use any servlet 2.4 container, then consider using it embedded with the Winstone container:

http://winstone.sourceforge.net/#embedding

You have now reduced your problem to a single executable JAR, for which plenty of installers exist.  Which one to choose depends on the actual circumstances.

Comment: Use an installer that Can handle that.

Comment: Only have found http://www.advancedinstaller.com/ but it's not free. Any open source suggestion?