# How to create an installer for java web application

Tags: java

How to create an installer for java web application that will install postgresql, jre and tomcat alongwith the application itself? Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create an installer for a Java EE Web application in a single installer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10456741/how-to-create-an-installer-for-a-java-ee-web-application-in-a-single-installer)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the platform.  For Windows, I'd look at InnoSetup:

http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply :)but Inno Setup can create executable file for one application but i want to bundle jre and tomcat along with my apllication how can i do that

Answer (score 0):

NSIS is easy and configurable. Take a look at it

http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page